# Mostrar bordes de tabla desde echo

Tags: css

Tengo un echo que muestra los datos de una tabla. Parte del código es el siguiente:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['Nombre'] . ' ' . $row['Apellidos'] . ' ' . $row['Edad'] .  '<br>';
}
```

El caso es que los datos se muestran correctamente, pero aparecen los datos de la tabla sin borde. Lo que quiero es que la tabla muestre los bordes.

Antes de ponerme con css. Tengo el siguiendo codigo con html dentro del echo:
´´´

```
echo "<table border='1'> ";

echo "<tr> ";

echo "<TD><b>id</b></TD> ";

echo "<TD><b>Nombre</b></TD> ";

echo "<TD><b>Apellidos</b></TD> ";

echo "<TD><b>Edad</b></TD> ";
echo "</tr> ";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

echo "<tr> ";

echo "<td>$row[id]</td> ";

echo "<td>$row[Nombre]</td> ";

echo "<td>$row[Apellidos]</td> ";
echo "<td>$row[Edad]</td> ";
echo "</tr> ";
echo "</table> ";
}
```

Me da el siguiente error:
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_row() in C:\wamp64\www\paginacion\index5.php on line 52
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_row() in C:\wamp64\www\paginacion\index5.php on line 52
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0003  404784  {main}( )   ...\index5.php:0

´´´
Le he agregado el echo despues de la variable results

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM alumnos LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


echo "<table border='1'> ";

echo "<tr> ";

echo "<TD><b>id</b></TD> ";

echo "<TD><b>Nombre</b></TD> ";

echo "<TD><b>Apellidos</b></TD> ";

echo "<TD><b>Edad</b></TD> ";
echo "</tr> ";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<tr> ";

echo "<td>$row[id]</td> ";

echo "<td>$row[Nombre]</td> ";

echo "<td>$row[Apellidos]</td> ";
echo "<td>$row[Edad]</td> ";
echo "</tr> ";
echo "</table> ";
}
```

Comment: ¿Y ya le aplicaste algún CSS para ello?

Comment: No, no le he aplicado. No se como hacerlo si mezclando php y html o php puro.

Comment: Aplicale CSS a las etiquetas de la tabla que quieres que tengan borde

Comment: El error se debe a que seguro estás usando una versión reciente de PHP donde todas las funciones *`mysql_*`* han sido removidas, entonces debes usar o mysqli o PDO

Comment: le he añadido mysqli pero ahora me muestra solo el primer registro dentro de la tabla y el resto sin formato.

Comment: Entonces edita la pregunta con lo mas reciente que hiciste por que ahora claramente  el problema ya no esta en como aplicar estilos